# Symfony 2 subform not bindig data

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a form that is not directly related  to a doctrine entity but some of his subforms are

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
      $builder
          ->add('Email','email')
          ->add('ShippingAddress',new AddressType($this->Order->getStore()))
          ->add('SameAddress','checkbox',array('required' => false))
          ->add('BillingAddress',new AddressType($this->Order->getStore()))
          ->setData(array('Email' => $this->Order->getEmail(),
                          'ShippingAddress' => $this->Order->getShippingAddress(),                                                                                                                                                                 
                          'BillingAddress' => $this->Order->getBillingAddress()))
      ;
 }
```

the first time I post the form

`$billingAddress = $formstep1->get('BillingAddress')->getData();`

returns the correct data from the fields and can be saved  when I try to edit the form the Shipping and Billing forms return preseted data

but if i access to the field inside this forms I get the corrrect data 
`$formstep1->get('ShippingAddress')->get('LastNames')->getData());`

Why is this happening?

Can't I set data in builForm and expect the form to bind data to this objects ?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't inject `order` as an argument. A form type is created only once and it'll be shared across all your forms. What you need is to look at `SET_DATA` form event. Google it. I'll try to post an example later.

Comment: thanks @meze I am try to set the data in the Pre_set_data event  but I cannot access to the `form` children with `form->get('Field')` the application gives an  error  child Field doesn't exists